# How to deal with nested callbacks in a clean way?

Tags: javascript, react.js, axios

I am currently migrating some code from class-based components to function components using hooks in *React*. Where I have come across a piece of code that works as expected but there are 3 *Axios* calls that are dependent on input from the first Axios call.

First Axios call returns *order amount* and *merchant ID* that are required for the second API to execute and the third API requires order ID and customer ID.

How can I deal with nested callbacks and write some clean, clear and readable code?

```
function getOrderDetails(customerId, token) {
  const orderDetailsPayload = {
    customerId,
    source: 'source'
  };
  setLoader(true);
  firstApi(orderDetailsPayload, token)
    .then(res => {
      setMerchantName(res.merchantName);
      setMerchantRedirectLink(res.merchantPlatformLink);
      if (res.orderAmount) {
        orderDetails(res);
        const emiPayload = {
          orderAmount: res.orderAmount,
          merchantId: res.merchantId
        };
        secondApi(emiPayload)
          .then(res => {
            console.log('EMI Response : ', res);
            if (res.data.status_code === 200) {
              setLoader(false);
              emiDetails(res.data);
            } else {
              setLoader(false);
              setAlert(true);
              console.log('EMI Details not present');
              setErrorMsg(res.data.message);
              setRoute('SignUp');
            }
          })
          .finally(() => {
            setLOADERemiCalculator(false);
          });
        const redirectionPayload = {
          customerId,
          orderId: res.orderId
        };
        thirdApi(redirectionPayload).then(res => {
          console.log('Redirection Response : ', res);
          if (res.data.status_code === 200) {
            setLoader(false);
            redirectionDetails(res.data);
            setRedirection(true);
            setMerchantRedirectLink(res.data.redirectionInfo.redirectionUrl);
          } else {
            setLoader(false);
            setRedirection(false);
            console.log('Redirection URL not present');
          }
        });
      } else {
        setLoader(false);
        setAlert(true);
        console.log('Order Amount missing');
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops something went wrong please contact customer care'
        );
        setLOADERemiCalculator(false);
        setRoute('SignUp');
      }
    })
    .catch(exception => {
      setLoader(false);
      console.log('getCheckoutApprovedProduct exception : ', exception);
      setAlert(true);
      setErrorMsg(
        'Oops something went wrong please contact customer care'
      );
      setRoute('SignUp');
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLOADERgetOrderDetails(false);
      console.log('Finally block:getOrderDetails');
    });
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to break this up into many smaller functions. This thing is pretty large and nested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the async/await syntax, its purpose is exactly cleaning up nested callbacks like this.

Comment: I have added async and await to my code and updated my question. Please check.

Comment: You need to put an `await` for each promise. You can check this guide from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) for a starter on this.